# JavaScript inside an <img title="<a href='#' onClick='alert('Hello World!')>The Link</a>" /> possible?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, dom-events

```
<img title="<a href='#' onClick='alert('Hello World!')>The Link</a>" />
```

So I've got some specific question.. I already know that I can work with attributes inside a TITLE attribute.. But can I work with             events inside a TITLE attribute?

(btw - It seems like a rubbish code, but this already works as is should on my web project - I just need a way to use some Javascript on this sheathed link.)

I USE **Jquery** framework.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, this is, as you say "rubbish code". If it works as should, it is because browsers try to "read the writer's mind" - in other words, they have algorithms to try to make sense of "rubbish code", guess at the probable intent and internally change it into something that actually makes sense.

In other words, your code only works by accident, and probably not in all browsers.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello World!')"><img title="The Link" /></a>
```

Comment: Is this possible within ajax get method?  Such as return '<a onClick="' + alert(DocId) + '" title="' + DocId + '" download target="_blank" href=\\RemoveDocuments\\' + DocId + 'class ="remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>';

Answer (score 14):

When you click on the image you'll get the alert:

```
<img src="logo1.jpg" onClick='alert("Hello World!")'/>
```

if this is what you want.

Comment: apparently this way isn't "standardized" however? http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html

Answer (score 5):

Im my browser, this doesn't work at all. The tooltip field doesn't show a link, but `<a href='#' onClick='alert('Hello World!')>The Link</a>`.
I'm using FF 3.6.12.

You'll have to do this by hand with JS and CSS. Begin [here](http://dzineblog.com/2008/10/30-tooltips-scripts.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
<img title="<a href="javascript:alert('hello world')">The Link</a>" />
```

Comment: This code won't work, as `title` will evaluate as `"<a href="`, with the rest of the code throwing a syntax error. Please actually **test** your code before posting it as an answer, and provide some [context surrounding your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). I also recommend reviewing the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write great answers.

Answer (score 2):

no, you can't do that, but you can use event handlers to change the title:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onmouseover="this.title='it is now ' + new Date()" />
```

Comment: I don't want to change the title text - I wont something like this: onClick css #Videodiv opacity.animate to 1  ^^

Comment: That's no problem if you attach an event handler, but don't do it inline, use a framework like JQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Events