# I can't click a hyperlink on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I design website, I try to use a href="http://www.google.com"

But I found that I can't go to the Google when I click the hyperlink.

[Please see the website here](http://abi.maxinrui.com/)

But if I click it on the source code, it works.

Anyone has a solutions for that?

Thanks!

OK, go to http://abi.maxinrui.com/     then click "Click me"   it should be link to Google, but it's not, while you click that in the source code, you can.

Also, I can not switch between radio button, please check http://abi.maxinrui.com/#slide-5

Comment: Try `http://www.google.com`

Comment: This is very basic `HTML` and few searches, if not one would easily solve your problem.

Comment: It is "Click Here"? Not "Click me".

Comment: Yes, that's the link.

Comment: @Felix  No it's not, someone says it's because e.preventDefault() I don't know how to disable it for some particular elements. And I can't delete all e.preventDefault() function from js file, it's too large

Comment: You also need to make your text a better contrast, as is it is very hard to read the titles over the photo on your website :)

Comment: Now the links are dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the `href` value of your anchor is invalid.

You need to place `//` after `:` in your URL, so use:

```
http://www.google.com
```

instead of:

```
http//:www.google.com
```

---

Seem like your link cannot go to Google because you've used `e.preventDefault()` to all the anchors in your site. Especially when you've utilized one-page navigation like that.

So search for this line in your javascript code:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

I'd suggest you to give a specific class to any anchor that you want to use `e.preventDefault()` instead of target all the anchors like what you're doing at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>
```

Also, note the `http://` in the URL.

Comment: OK, I understand that was just a typo. I think that Felix's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT BASED ON THE CLARIFICATION OF THE OP**

Here a image that I took from your site

[image: ScreenShoot]

I just moved the link as you created it, to below the tag <kbd>body</kbd> and it worked. It looks like it's just a problem with the encapsulation. The "Click" itself never occur.

[Just add an `alert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283614/javascript-inside-an-img-title-a-href-onclick-alerthello-worldthe) to the tag <kbd>a</kbd> to see for yourself.

Just remove the `data-slide="1"` from your div `slide-1` and the link will work.

---

<strike>You made a small mistake when you typed your link.</strike>

You can't call an url the way you did (`http//:www.google.com`) you need to call it in the right format (`http://www.google.com`).

so the result will be

```
<a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>
```

**So why do I need to type http:// in?**

> The http:// is very important! You should try to get in the habit of
>   always typing this in when you are entering a URL (Universal Resource
>   Locator), the stuff in the address bar above. It tells your computer
>   that you are retrieving a HyperText document, rather than some other
>   type of file. Web files are written in HTML (HyperText Markup
>   Language) and HTML files are HyperText documents.

**But I never type it in and I always get the web page I want!**

> Actually, if you look, you will notice that your web browser
>   (Netscape, or Internet Explorer) has put it in for you. There is an
>   exception which is mentioned farther on.

[Source](http://cowboyfrank.net/archive/http.htm)

Comment: Thanks, it just a typo, it's not the real problem, thanks all the same, but if you click the link , you will find the real problem is.